# Is there any way to display calendar of last month by default?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
     $(function() {
            var date = new Date();
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1, 1);
         $('#datepicker').datepicker({defaultDate: date});
      });
     </script>
     <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

I want to get the last month calendar by default.While using     `<input    type="text">` it show the current date so is there any way to do it.
 Can any one help me ?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Comment: are you using jQuery's calendar..???

Comment: <input id="from" type="date" value="2015-03-01"/> but when it comes to the next month it wont show up 'may' .It has to show by default.

Comment: no i'm using the html5 date format.I dont know how to dispaly the last month by default without using values.I'm not using any jquery files for it.Will the jquery calendar works in this case then it will be ok

Comment: Please clarify your example. It is unclear what you want at the moment. Also very few browsers support `input type="date"` at the moment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jquery you can display like following way.

**HTML:**

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
        var date = new Date();
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1, 1);
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({defaultDate: date});
  });
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c1dwc6zc/)

Comment: ketan can you help me out of this.i added jQuery UI 1.9.2 still its not working

Comment: You have to include. http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js and  http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js both.

Comment: how can i store the value by default in my input box.